# set title of presented view

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am using following code to switch view when click on other tab to show a different content(not sure whether it's propert way to do that, but now I can change the conent when clicking on the tab bottom button)

```
-(void) favBtnClick:(id*)sender{
    NSLog(@"fav btn clicked");
    FavouriteViewController *tgt = [[FavouriteViewController alloc]init];
    [self presentViewController:tgt animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Now that the view was drawn from the very top of the screen, and I think it will be neater to add a title in the view so I tried following in the target view of `videDidLoad` function, but nothing happens, the title was not shown:

```
UINavigationBar* navbar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 50)];
    UINavigationItem* item = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"title text"];
    [navbar pushNavigationItem:item animated:YES];
    navbar.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:navbar];
```

How to make this work?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `title` property of FavouriteViewController instance.

Comment: You do it after additing navigation bar?

Comment: no in the parent viewController right  after `FavouriteViewController *tgt = [[FavouriteViewController alloc]init];`

Comment: try to remove additing of navigation bar. Then after creating tgt and setting title, create UINavigationController with tgt like that:
`UINavigationController * nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tgm];`